# Zurb Image Size

Tags: html, css, html-email, zurb-ink

I'm using Zurb Ink to create atemplate for the first time; it's great, but I cannot get my head around a certain problem.

Everything works fine when I view the HTML in my browser, but I'm unfortunately required to send my email through a sending platform which takes the liberty of adjusting the code I've written.

The problem I'm having is with image size. For some reason, an image I'm using, which is 580px wide, sizes itself to 576px when sent through the email platform. I have looked through the code repeatedly and checked around online but I can't find anything, so an help is VERY much appreciated.

```
<!--header row-->
<table class="row header-bar" style="border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; width: 100%; position: relative; display: block; background: #4480ba; padding: 0px;" bgcolor="#4480ba">
    <tbody>
        <tr style="vertical-align: top; text-align: left; padding: 0;" align="left">
            <td class="wrapper last" style="word-break: break-word; -webkit-hyphens: auto; -moz-hyphens: auto; hyphens: auto; border-collapse: collapse !important; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; position: relative; color: #222222; font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; font-size: 14px; margin: 0; padding: 10px 0px 0px;" align="left" valign="top">
                <table class="twelve columns" style="border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; width: 580px; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0;">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr style="vertical-align: top; text-align: left; padding: 0;" align="left">
                            <td class="nine sub-columns" style="word-break: break-word; -webkit-hyphens: auto; -moz-hyphens: auto; hyphens: auto; border-collapse: collapse !important; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; min-width: 0px; width: 75%; color: #222222; font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; font-size: 14px; margin: 0; padding: 0px 10px 10px 0px;" align="left" valign="top">
                                <img style="outline: none; text-decoration: none; -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; max-width: 80%; float: left; clear: both; display: block; padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; margin-left: 5px; margin-right: 5px;" class="text-pad alumni-logo" src="" alt="" width="237" height="80" align="left" />
                            </td>
                            <td class="three sub-columns" style="word-break: break-word; -webkit-hyphens: auto; -moz-hyphens: auto; hyphens: auto; border-collapse: collapse !important; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; min-width: 0px; width: 25%; color: #222222; font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; font-size: 14px; margin: 0; padding: 0px 10px 10px 0px;" align="left" valign="top">
                                <img style="outline: none; text-decoration: none; -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; max-width: 100%; float: none; clear: both; display: block; margin: 0 auto;" class="center" src="http://www.jampaper.com/userFiles/productImages/tn_02561_Orange_6_1_2_x_6_1_2_Square_Envelopes.jpg" alt="" width="80" height="80" align="none" />
                            </td>
                            <td class="expander" style="word-break: break-word; -webkit-hyphens: auto; -moz-hyphens: auto; hyphens: auto; border-collapse: collapse !important; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; visibility: hidden; width: 0px; color: #222222; font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; font-size: 14px; margin: 0; padding: 0;" align="left" valign="top">
                                &nbsp;
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<!--/header row-->
<!--big image row-->
<table class="row" style="border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; width: 100%; position: relative; display: block; padding: 0px;">
    <tbody>
        <tr style="vertical-align: top; text-align: left; padding: 0;" align="left">
            <td class="wrapper last intro-image" style="word-break: break-word; -webkit-hyphens: auto; -moz-hyphens: auto; hyphens: auto; border-collapse: collapse !important; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; position: relative; color: #222222; font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; font-size: 14px; margin: 0; padding: 0 0px 0px;" align="left" valign="top">
                <table class="twelve columns" style="border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; width: 580px; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0;">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr style="vertical-align: top; text-align: left; padding: 0;" align="left">
                            <td style="word-break: break-word; -webkit-hyphens: auto; -moz-hyphens: auto; hyphens: auto; border-collapse: collapse !important; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; color: #222222; font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; font-size: 14px; margin: 0; padding: 0px 0px 10px;" align="left" valign="top">
                                <img style="outline: none; text-decoration: none; -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; max-width: 100%; float: none; clear: both; display: block; padding-top: 0 !important; margin: 0 auto;" class="center intro-image" src="http://www.nagelphotography.com/img/s2/v4/p176518365-3.jpg" alt="" width="580" align="none" />
                            </td>
                            <td class="expander" style="word-break: break-word; -webkit-hyphens: auto; -moz-hyphens: auto; hyphens: auto; border-collapse: collapse !important; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; visibility: hidden; width: 0px; color: #222222; font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; font-size: 14px; margin: 0; padding: 0;" align="left" valign="top">
                                &nbsp;
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<!--/big image row-->
```

I understand this might be a bit of a long shot but I really cannot figure out why this image is not 580px when the screen is wide enough to support it. For reference, at smaller sizes the problem persists, but the difference is a smaller number of pixels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone comes across this problem in the future - you may be interested to know that the reason the image was out of line was the expander cell below was taking up space, due to the fact that the   character had been added by the email platform I was using. Normally in Ink expanders have no size at all.